# lxml Python, read text and tree for given structure of XML file

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm trying to get text and id under Node, see example file here: [example.xml](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/titipata/e9c6361a416dc56f1f8e1eb046982594/raw/ac2e9694aa9ade0be38c08500f0ab2645c1d7535/9407011.az-scixml.xml)

However, it doesn't have the structure as normal XML file. The structure is as following:

```
<TextWithNodes><Node id="0"/>
<Node id="1"/>
<Node id="2"/>9407011<Node id="9"/>
<Node id="10"/>ACL<Node id="13"/> <Node id="14"/>1994<Node id="18"/>
<Node id="19"/> Lg.Pr.Dc <Node id="29"/>
```

The output I want is a list of `start_node`, `end_node` and `text_between_node`. I'm not sure if I can use `lxml` library to do that.

Currently, I use

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('9407011.az-scixml.xml')
nodes = tree.xpath('//TextWithNodes')[0].getchildren()
node = nodes[0] # example one node
print(node.text) # this give empty string because you don't have closing same id
```

Comment: Please show your attempt and your desired result using posted sample or link.

Answer (score 1):

Using XPath might work for you. Comparing `normalize-space()` to an empty string will eliminate the nodes with no following text.

This might work for you:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
root = ET.XML(b'''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<GateDocument version="3">
<TextWithNodes><Node id="0"/>
<Node id="1"/>
<Node id="2"/>9407011<Node id="9"/>
<Node id="10"/>ACL<Node id="13"/> <Node id="14"/>1994<Node id="18"/>
<Node id="19"/> Lg.Pr.Dc <Node id="29"/>
</TextWithNodes></GateDocument>''')

# Grab each 'Node' element:
#  Only if the element has an 'id' attribute, and only if
#  the first sibling is a text node that isn't
#  all wihtespace and only if
#  the second sibling is a 'Node' with an 'id'
for r in root.xpath('''//Node[@id]
                           [following-sibling::node()
                               [1]
                               [self::text()]
                               [normalize-space() != ""]]
                           [following-sibling::node()
                               [2]
                               [self::Node[@id]]]'''):
    # All elements that satisfy that above XPath should
    # also satisfy the requirements for the next line
    print (r.get('id'), repr(r.tail), r.getnext().get('id'))
```